# (DearImGui, OpenGL 3.3): Rendering an imgui user interface on a texture

Tags: imgui

I want to render imgui on an opengl texture (using render to texture) instead of a view port. Then simulate mouse and keyboard input instead of directly passing the input to it.

What would be the steps to do it?